# SQl ANY or ALL Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table which I query to get few columns to load data to application.

Suppose I have following columns from a select query:

```
Account| Employee | Amount | Position
123    | EMP123   | 1000   |
143    | EMP123   | 1000   |
153    | EMP123   | 1000   |
163    | EMP123   | 1000   |
100    | EMP456   | 1000   |
143    | EMP456   | 1000   |
153    | EMP456   | 1000   |
163    | EMP456   | 1000   |
```

I want to select position of employee based on account `123`.

So for all those employees which have account `123` in records return their position as for example `Temp` else `Perm`.

So expected output based on example above;

```
Account| Employee | Amount | Position
123    | EMP123   | 1000   | Temp
143    | EMP123   | 1000   | Temp
153    | EMP123   | 1000   | Temp
163    | EMP123   | 1000   | Temp
100    | EMP456   | 1000   | Perm
143    | EMP456   | 1000   | Perm
153    | EMP456   | 1000   | Perm
163    | EMP456   | 1000   | Perm
```

I have got the result using ANY clause but that is very very very slow and i have more than 100000 records :|

Query i use;

```
Select ACCOUNT,amount,EMPLOYEE,
  CASE 
  WHEN EMPLOYEE = ANY (SELECT EMPLOYEE FROM Table1 WHERE ACCOUNT = 123) 
  THEN 'Temp'
  ELSE 'Perm'
  END AS 'Position'
```

Any tip would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The query itself doesn't look unreasonable, meaning any re-write is unlikely to dramatically change performance. As Dmitry says, it's time to be looking at the execution plan and looking for missed indexing opportunities.

Comment: Besides tuning, which is something you should investigate, you could try rewriting the `CASE` expression to use an `EXISTS` clause.  But, that still might give the same execution plan.

Comment: you have  more than 100000 records, if it's unique then try by creating a unique index on account column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `exists`:

```
select Account,
       Employee,
       Amount,
       case when exists(select 1 from my_table
                        where Employee = t.Employee
                          and Account = 123)
            then 'Temp' else 'Perm' end Position
from my_table t
```

Moreover, you could create indexes on `Account` and `Employee` columns.

Comment: Thanks all for your help Guys. I ended up creating views to simplify things and use Michal query to get the data. So approx 300000 records in 15 seconds . I think that's reasonable!!    Though  application owner wouldn't agree :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using a windowed aggregate:

```
declare @t table(Account int, Employee char(6), Amount int)
insert into @t(Account, Employee, Amount) values
(123,'EMP123',1000),
(143,'EMP123',1000),
(153,'EMP123',1000),
(163,'EMP123',1000),
(100,'EMP456',1000),
(143,'EMP456',1000),
(153,'EMP456',1000),
(163,'EMP456',1000)

select
    *,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Account='123' THEN 'Temp' ELSE 'Perm' END) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee)
from @t
```

As I said in the comments though, it's doubtful that any re-write will offer a massive performance boost and it's more likely that you're missing appropriate indexes. If it's egregious enough, when you generate an execution plan for either query (the one from your question or the one here), the system should highlight a missing index<sup>1</sup>.

Result:

```
Account     Employee Amount      
----------- -------- ----------- ----
123         EMP123   1000        Temp
143         EMP123   1000        Temp
153         EMP123   1000        Temp
163         EMP123   1000        Temp
100         EMP456   1000        Perm
143         EMP456   1000        Perm
153         EMP456   1000        Perm
163         EMP456   1000        Perm
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the suggestions aren't always, how shall we say, stellar. But if it's saying there's a missing index, it's usually right that *some* additional index(es) will improve your query times. But don't blindly apply all such suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Damien, I will test this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can use in

```
Select ACCOUNT,amount,EMPLOYEE,
  CASE 
  WHEN EMPLOYEE in (SELECT EMPLOYEE FROM Table1 WHERE ACCOUNT = 123) 
  THEN 'Temp'
  ELSE 'Perm'
  END AS 'Position'
```

Comment: Thanks Zaynul but this would not give me the correct position for EMP123 when account is  143 . So what my intention is that if employee have amount against account 123  update position as temp for all occurrences of that employee.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select ACCOUNT,amount,EMPLOYEE,
  CASE 
  WHEN EMPLOYEE like '%123%' then 'temp' else 'perm' end as position
  from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT,amount,EMPLOYEE
, CASE WHEN ISNULL(T2.HasAnyPosition, 0) > 0 THEN 'Perm' 
ELSE 'Temp' END AS Position
FROM EmployeeTable T1
OUTER APPLY
(
 SELECT COUNT(0) HasAnyPosition
 From PositionTable T2
 WHERE T2.Account = T1.Account
) T2
```